# Automatically start up Virtual Machine and run a script within the VM

Tags: virtual-machine, automation

I'm looking to automate a certain process. On my host machine, I would like to start up an instance of a VM, and once the VM has loaded, run a command line script contained within the VM. I would also like to pass an argument from the host machine to the command line script inside the VM.

Is it at all possible to have a script do this on my host machine automatically? If so, what kind of tools / VM program do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on the involved OSes. I'll try to give you an idea on how to achieve that, but I can't be specific since you gave not much detail. Also, keep in mind that this is just one approach, you could achieve the same thing in many other ways.

- share a drive (or partition, folder) between your hosts and guest. It is sufficient that the host has write permission, and the guest has read permission.
- create a script on the host machine that
  creates a file on the shared drive, with the argument written in it and
  boots the virtual machine.
- create a script on the guest OS that reads the argument from the file in the shared drive and executes the command with the argument.
- make sure that the script on the guest machine is run at startup.